# Python connecting to FTPS server filezilla violation of protocol error

Tags: python, ftp

Question I want to be able to connect to and download a file from my remote  FTP filezilla. I am able to connect however as soon as it executes "ftp.retrlines('LIST')" I get an error as described below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Here is my script

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS

ftp = FTP_TLS('111.111.111.111)  # Hidden IP for my FTP SERVER 
ftp.login('ftpuser', 'ftppassword12345') 
ftp.prot_p()                      # securing data connection explicitly
ftp.cwd('/')                      # change working directory to the root

ftp.retrlines('LIST')             # This is where it fails
```

Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ftps_.py", line 7, in <module>
    ftp.retrlines('LIST')            
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 735, in retrlines
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 376, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 713, in ntransfercmd
    server_hostname=self.host)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 352, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 579, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 808, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)
```